# Making Text look like it's being typed in the Python Shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, python-3.3

So far the only method I've come up with is clearing the console then displaying the string with one more letter. Suggestions?

Current Code:

```
import os
import time
In=list(input("Text to be displayed: "))
Out=""
Move=[]
print("-")
while len(Move)<len(In):
    Move+=["/","|","\\","-"]
for a in range(0,len(In)):
    if In[a]==" ":
      x=.3
    elif In[a] in ",';:!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}":
      x=.25
    elif In[a] in "aeiouzxcvbnm1234567890AEIOUZXCVBNM":
      x=.2
    else:
      x=.15
    os.system('cls')
    Out+=In[a]
    print(Out+Move[a])
    time.sleep(x)
os.system('cls')
print(Out)
input()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `print()` with `end=''` to stay on the same line, and `flush = True` for the timing:

```
import time
Move+=["/","|","\\","-"]
text = input('Text to be displayed: ')
for i in text:
    print(i, end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.1)
print('\n')
```

This runs as:

```
bash-3.2$ python3.3 test.py
Text to be displayed: This is a test
This is a test

bash-3.2$
```

### Addressing your comment, use the below code:

```
import time
Move=["/","|","\\","-",""]
text = input('Text to be displayed: ')
for i in range(len(text)):
    print(text[i]+Move[i%5], end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.1)
print('\n')
```

Comment: Fixed the paren on print for you. :D

Comment: Note that in Python3.3 you can use `print(i, end='', flush=True)` instead of requiring the `import sys` and `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: Is there an easy way to ad the character on the end, to look like its loading the text, otherwise the code is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *to look like its loading the text*?

Comment: My original code will display text:  -  :  h\  :  he|  :  hel/  :  hell-  :  hello

Comment: all that your new code does is puts one of the loading characters between each letter being output, I'm looking to display the string with one more character at a time and also have a different loading character at the end each time

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you just want the string to appear one character at a time, with a delay between each character.

```
import time
from sys import stdout

In=list(input("Text to be displayed: "))
for x in In:
  print(x, end='')
  stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(0.1)

print("\n")
```

Comment: can you explain what
    stdout.flush()
is doing exactly?

Comment: @JakeTheMC, `stdout` is normally buffered in memory, and the flush will cause the buffer to be flushed to the terminal so the user can see it.